# Abstracting middleware function

Tags: javascript, express

So I found that I have repeat code for my middleware Express functions.

First function:

```
const isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const requestingUser = await knex('users')
                                  .first('current_role')
                                  .where('id','=',req.user.id)

    requestingUser.current_role !== 'admin' ? res.sendStatus(403) : next()

  } catch (error) {
    res.send({error})
  }
}
```

Second function:

```
const isAdminOrRecruiter = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const requestingUser = await knex('users')
                                  .first('current_role')
                                  .where('id','=',req.user.id)
    const isNotAllowed = requestingUser.current_role !== 'admin' && requestingUser.current_role !==  'recruiter'
    isNotAllowed ? res.sendStatus(403) : next()

  } catch (error) {
    res.send({error})
  }
}
```

My question is how can I make one abstract function like `isAllowed(['admin])` so only admin can go through or `isAllowed(['admin','recruiter'])` so it can allow only admins and recruiters to go through?

The specific problem I have is with args - there are already three of them and not sure where to put fourth one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of higher order functions to derive your current ones. You would have a function that takes a list of roles and returns another function that uses that list of roles to check if the current user is assigned to any of them and if so allow access:

```js
const isRole = (...roles) => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const requestingUser = await knex('users')
                                  .first('current_role')
                                  .where('id','=',req.user.id)
    const isAllowed = roles.some(role => role == requestingUser.current_role);
    isAllowed ? next() : res.sendStatus(403) 

  } catch (error) {
    res.send({error})
  }
}

const isAdmin = isRole("admin");
const isAdminOrRecruiter = isRole("admin", "recruiter");
```

Comment: @jeand'arme you can certainly just use `isRole` directly, if you wish. If that makes more sense then go for it - I just tried to keep your current code structure intact.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I realised that if I would use it directly then I might miss `(req, res, next)` args (would I?). I'm just not sure how exactly higher-order functions work

Comment: @jeand'arme a higher order function is a fancy name for a function that accepts or returns another function. In this case `isAdmin` and `isAdminOrRecruiter` would behave *exactly* like before - you'd still call them as `isAdmin(req, res, next)`. If you use `isRole` directly, then you'd call `isRole("admin")(req, res, next)`

Comment: Thanks! That's very well explained. Thanks for examples as well!